# Finding Lines of Code in Suvbversion

Tags: svn, lines-of-code

Friends, can anybody know finding lines of code in Subversion? As I am new to Subversion, I dont know much about it. Basically, earlier we used Clearcase as our Version Control System.

One of our Manager requires Lines of Code (KLOC) from a particular modules in one of the module. If anybody knew about Lines added, changed/modified and removed in SVN, please let me know ASAP. It's every mandatory formr.

Thanks,
Suuresh Kumar.

Comment: Assuming [`cloc`](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) output is suitable, `svn co /repo/path /tmp/repo; cloc /tmp/repo`

Answer (score 1):

Try SVN blame.
It shows file and state of every lines in a range of revision.
If you use a tourtoise svn:
right click on file, tourtoise svn -> blame
if not:
svn blame PATH_TO_FILE from repository folder

Answer (score 1):

You should try an svn statistics/reporting tool such as [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org)
It will report and graph statistics such as LOC and churn over time. I believe it is possible to do so on a sub-repository (module) level as well.